# Navigation Library for React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation

I've been thinking of which long term solution navigation library to use for react native. I'm comparing react-navigation and react-native-navigation (both their version 2) as of the moment.

My criteria would be stability and performance. Any suggestion which one to use?

Answer (score 0):

React Native Router Flux https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux offers great integration with Redux and I have never experienced any stability issues. The major issues I did encounter where though:

- Customizing the Navbar was a pain
- Handling the Android Back button required me to implement a `routingUtility` which checked the currentPage and then performed Navigation. It also has a lot more activity with far less issues and pull requests and is more frequently updated.